# divide two column groups contained in 1 row group

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Let's say I have a table where my row group is month, 2 column groups are:

- one based on onsite status,
- and the other on offshore status

Table:

```
month  [onsite]  [offshore]  [total]   [%]
jan     2         3           5       (2/3)
```

How to achieve the % column?

I can only apply the count function in case I have 1 column group and 1 total in the whole.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `=ReportItems!Textbox123.Value/ReportItems!Textbox456.Value` on the % expression (change the id's of the textboxes accordingly)